# how to add second image on ImageView

Tags: android, imageview

I am a beginner Android developer, so I'm sorry if the answer to this question is obvious.

I want to add two pictures to `imageView`. The first picture will be bigger and its position won't change. And the second will be smaller and its position will change, vertically (I think there is 16 combinations where it could be located). The position of the second image will change only when the user presses the button. Is there any way to set two pictures into one bitmap and then draw them to `ImageView`?

Comment: make it li'l more clear.

Comment: I just need to add two images toogether and draw them to ImageView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `set two pictures into one bitmap and then draw them to ImageView` is an requirement, I would suggest the following:

You can create a canvas from larger bitmap, and draw your smaller bitmap on it, and display the drawn bitmap on Image View.

You have to calculate the position of drawing tough.

```
Bitmap largeImage; // Get it with your own approach, this refers to larger image
Bitmap smallImage; // Get it with your own approach, this refers to small image
ImageView yourImageView;

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(largeImage);
//0f and 0f refers to coordinates of drawing, you may want to do some calculation here
// since you have like 16 different positions
canvas.drawBitmap(smallImage, 0f, 0f, null); 

yourImageView.setImageBitmap(largeImage);
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for, but it doesn't shows me smallImage on top of it.

Comment: It was my mistake, i fix it, thank you u solved mi problem :)

Answer (score 0):

An ImageView is related to a single bitmap. You could draw yourself the bitmap and then pass it to the ImageView or you could use other component, like a gridlayout (or gridview) with the static image for background and the dynamic image wherever you want.

Sorry if I did not get your question right...

Comment: Gridview isn't exactly what i was looking for. I just want to make bitmap from two pictures and then draw it to ImageView. But i don't know how... but thanks for your anwser

Comment: You could use canvas for it... Instantiate a Canvas from the static image and draw the other with drawBitmap() on top of it...

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is following, here's the XML:

```
<RelativeLayout 
android:id="@+id/view_base"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_parent"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/circle" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_child"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
```

Here's the code with two methods:

```
//This is what I recommend
RelativeLayout view_base=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.view_base);

ImageView iv_parent=(imageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_parent);
ImageView iv_child=(imageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_child);

yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) {
        iv_child.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image);
    }
});

//This is how you want it
RelativeLayout view_base=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.view_base);

ImageView iv_parent=(imageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_parent);
ImageView iv_child=(imageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_child);

ImageView iv_single=(imageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_single);


yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
        iv_child.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image);
        iv_single.setImageBitmap(getMergedBitmap());
    }
});

//This method will convert view to bitmap
private Bitmap getMergedBitmap(){
    view_base.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    view_base.buildDrawingCache();
    return view_base.getDrawingCache()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `FrameLayout` with two `ImageView`. And then set bitmap to that imageviews.